# Refresh and execute a program in Autoit

Tags: autoit

I want to make a program in autoit with a GUI - 2 buttons: the first button must refresh a web page (Ex: Google page) every 3 seconds, the second button must stop the refresh and do some operations on the web page. I'm ok with the first button, but I cannot exit from the loop with the second button and execute the operation I want. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot! This is the code:

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <GDIPlus.au3>

$Form1 = GUICreate("Example", 190, 133, 192, 124)
GUISetBkColor(0xFFFF00)
$Button1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("UPDATE", 3, 31 ,179, 37, 0)
$Button2 = GUICtrlCreateButton("EXECUTE", 3, 80 ,179, 37, 0)

GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 0x0000FF)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0x00FF00)
GUICtrlSetCursor (-1, 0)


GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 0x000000)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)


While 1
   $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
   Switch $nMsg
           Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                   Exit
           Case $button1

                 HotKeySet("{x}", "_Exit") ; Sets a shortcut to kill the script quickly. ESC
                 Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 3) ; This is to tell the script to only refresh the EXACT window, incase there are similar windows. Such as: Window 1, Window 2.
                 While 1 ; This begins a While LOOP
                       Sleep(3000) ; Tell the script to pause for 3 seconds
                       $title = WinGetTitle("Google - Mozilla Firefox", "") ; Grabs the exactly title and saves it to a variable to do an If statement against.
                       If WinExists($title) Then ; Check to see if the desired window is running.
                       WinActivate($title) ; If it is running, first activate the window.
                       WinWaitActive($title) ; This tells the script to not send the refresh key (F5) until the window has appeared.
                       Send("{F5}") ; This sends the F5 key to refresh the window.
                       Else ; This is an else statement to tell the script to do a different operation if the window is not running.
                         Sleep(10) ; Just a filler item to wait until the desired window is running.
                       EndIf ; End the If statement to continue the script.
                 WEnd ; Close the While LOOP
                 Func _Exit() ; This is the function that is linked to the kill switch, ESC. It tells the script to perform the following actions.
                 ExitLoop ; Block pressing "x"
              EndFunc ; Close the function up.

           Case $button2
                 ExitLoop ; stop the loop and make operations below
                 Send("{TAB}")
                 Send("^v")

EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <GDIPlus.au3>

Global $Go2 = True

$Form1 = GUICreate("Example", 190, 133, 192, 124)
GUISetBkColor(0xFFFF00)
$Button1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("UPDATE", 3, 31, 179, 37, 0)
$Button2 = GUICtrlCreateButton("EXECUTE", 3, 80, 179, 37, 0)

GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 0x0000FF)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, 0x00FF00)
GUICtrlSetCursor(-1, 0)


GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 0x000000)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

Local $hTimer = TimerInit()
While True
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
        Case $Button1
            $Go2 = True
            HotKeySet("!{e}", "_Exit") ; Sets a shortcut to kill the script quickly. ESC
            HotKeySet("{s}", "_ExitLoop") ; Sets a shortcut to kill the script quickly. ESC
            Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 3) ; This is to tell the script to only refresh the EXACT window, incase there are similar windows. Such as: Window 1, Window 2.
            While $Go2 ; Avoid getting stuck in the while loop forever
                If TimerDiff($hTimer) > 3000 Then
                    ConsoleWrite("Refreshing Mozilla" & @LF)
                    $title = WinGetTitle("Google - Mozilla Firefox", "") ; Grabs the exactly title and saves it to a variable to do an If statement against.
                    If WinExists($title) Then ; Check to see if the desired window is running.
                        WinActivate($title) ; If it is running, first activate the window.
                        WinWaitActive($title) ; This tells the script to not send the refresh key (F5) until the window has appeared.
                        Send("{F5}") ; This sends the F5 key to refresh the window.
                        $hTimer = TimerInit()
                        HotKeySet("{x}")
                    Else ; This is an else statement to tell the script to do a different operation if the window is not running.
;~                              Sleep(10) ; Just a filler item to wait until the desired window is running.
                    EndIf ; End the If statement to continue the script.
                EndIf
            WEnd
            $hTimer = TimerInit()
            HotKeySet("{x}")        ; Release hotkey
            HotKeySet("!{e}")       ; Release hotkeys
            ConsoleWrite("Exited loop" & @LF)
        Case $Button2
            ;you can't exit the loop from the $button1 here but there is a hotkey set to exit it, ALT + E
            Send("{TAB}")
            Send("^v")

    EndSwitch
WEnd
Exit

Func _Exit()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>_Exit

Func _ExitLoop()
    $Go2 = Not $Go2
EndFunc
```

P.S. I avoid using sleep because it pauses the script.

Comment: Look at my answer. up :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
Local $Refresh = 0 ; Set refresh OFF
Local $Timer = TimerInit()

Local $RefreshEvery = 3 ; seconds


Do

    $msg = GUIGetMsg()
    Select
        Case $msg = $BtnRefresh
            $Refresh = 1 ; Set refresh ON
        Case $msg = $btnStop
            $Refresh = 0 ; Set refresh OFF
    EndSelect


    If $Refresh And (TimerDiff($Timer) > $RefreshEvery*1000) Then
        RefreshBrowser()
        $Timer = TimerInit()
    EndIf


Until $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
```